# Web App is not loading after deploying

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-app-service-plans

I have a working app service named "matanwebserver" over a subscription in Azure. This is a website that I am working on. I work with Visual Studio.

Now I created another Web App on the same subscription that I will use as an integration site so I can test my code before publishing to the production site.
The name of the new Web App is "matanwebservertest". After publishing my project from Visual Studio to the new Web App, when I enter it's URL it seems like nothing happened, but it writes "Your App Service app is up and running".

What am I doing wrong?

**Added some screenshots for a better understanding of the issue**

1. In Visual Studio I do right click on the web app which is called
   "MatanWebServer" and choose "publish". Then I choose the new web app that I
   just created on Azure portal which called "matanwebserertest", and publish
   successfully.

[image]

2. This is the original (production) website. which its address is
   http://matanwebserver.azurewebsites.net

[image]

3. After publish to the matanwebservertest web app, I expect to see a "copy" of the original site, but it seems like nothing is there.

[image]

Comment: Have you check the project in the Kudu console? Your project exists or not?

Comment: @JoyWang It exists, I dragged a whole folder to the Kudu console, inside the rootwww and now it's a mess.
Is there a way to go back ?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by adding the command "dotnet YourArtifact.dll" command in:

mywebapp > Application Settings (Configuration) > General settings > Stack Settings -> Startup command

[image: Adding startup command to Azure webapp]

Comment: I tried this and in the log stream I get `Running user provided startup command... It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs`. I have the app service set up with .NET Core stack and version 3.1. Any ideas?

Comment: The "Startup Command" does not exist anymore in Azure general settings.  Where did it go?

Comment: Excelent, works for me!!! @JohnHenckel today, I went to the configuration and I could find it.

Comment: This option no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, when publishing web application to Azure Web App via the publish wizard of VS, you would see the following similar logs:

```
Updating file (brucewebapp01\bin\AspDotNet-MVC-Website.dll)
OR
Adding file (brucewebapp01\Scripts\respond.js)
```

> Your App Service app is up and running
>
> Go to your app's Quick Start guide in the Azure portal to get started or read our deployment documentation.

It seems that your web app only picks up the `hostingstart.html` default page which is automatically created after you created your web app. The default documents for your web app look like this:

[image]

As Joy Wang commented, you'd better check your deployed contents under your `matanwebserertest` web app and compare them with the web contents under your production web app via [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or Azure App Service Editor or FTP tools to make sure that you have correctly deployed the proper web contents into your test web app. Details you could follow [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).

Also, you could try to create a new web app and manually copy / drag the local published web contents into your new web app (`D:\home\site\wwwroot`) via KUDU or FTP tools to narrow this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To configure staging and production environment on Azure, use builtin feature "deployment slots". Follow these links to read more about deployment slots.

[Documentation to Set up staging environments in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing)

[Video Tutorial to setup Azure WebSites - Deployment Slots for Staging Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-websites-deployment-slots-for-staging-sites/)

[Enabling Deployment Slots To Safely Deploy Applications To Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/16/deploy-app-azure-app-service/)

Comment: Thanks, i have tried already the deployment slots feature, it does not work either. It still seems like nothing is on the website after publish.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the .NET version  I am using ASP.NET 4.6 for local builds  but selected its runtime as 3.5

Went to Configuration > General Settings and changed the .NET Version to 4.8  (this should only work if you are using ASP.NET  not Core)  did the trick for me.